I have an Excel macro that deletes a row if the cell in Column E is blank. I need the macro only to run on a set of rows that I manually select
I have a worksheet that needs to be edited, and to help with that I'm trying to create a macro to remove all the rows where a particular column (E in this case) is blank.
BUT, I need it to operate only on a range of rows I manually select because after it deletes the rows I have to do some fussy manual cleanup to the remaining rows from that selection. The rows fall into natural groupings that range from maybe 20 to several hundred rows and I want to select and work on one grouping at a time.
I've cobbled together the code below based on answers to some similar but not identical questions, but the code still runs through the entire worksheet rather than confining itself to the rows I've selected.
Sub DeleteRowIfCellBlank()
    
Dim r As Range, Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Selection

    For Each r In Rng.Cells ' .Cells is implied in For Each r in Rng
        Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

End Sub


Try just one line of code: Selection.EntireRow.Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete. This will fail if there are no blanks, but that can be handled.
